# pytest with async generator hangs after tests pass

Tags: pytest, python-asyncio

I have

```
from typing import AsyncIterable

import pytest


class Detector:
    async def find_events(self) -> AsyncIterable[int]:
        yield 1


class TestRunner:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def detector(self):
        return Detector()

    @staticmethod
    async def run_detector(detector):
        results = detector.find_events()
        result_list = []
        async for result in results:
            result_list.append(result)
        return result_list

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_detector(self, detector):
        results = await self.run_detector(detector)
        assert results
```

But the tester hangs after all the tests pass:
[image]

Comment: That isn’t valid syntax. Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: I fixed it so it's a valid syntax now.

Comment: The code as shown works without issue for me. How do you run the tests? What is the tester and do the tests work when invoked via pytest itself, i.e. running `pytest` on the terminal? Note that the code shown could even run without an actual event loop, it is very unlikely to contain an issue that leads to blocking (since it cannot block at all).